# Tradingview Multi Time Frame : how to plot a weekly high on a daily chart?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am new to pine script coding and I'd need some support.
I'd like to plot the week high on a daily chart using the Multi Time Frame option available in trading view. but I face a shift between my weekly high and line and my daily chart.

```
    //@version=4
    study(" My MTF Test", overlay=true)

    htfhigh = security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", high)
    plot(htfhigh, title="htfhigh", linewidth=2, style=plot.style_stepline)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MZSF.png)

I tried to offset the line which solves the issue but I'm missing the last week information when doing so.

```
    //@version=4
    study(" My MTF Test", overlay=true)

    htfhigh = security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", high)
    plot(htfhigh, title="htfhigh", linewidth=2, style=plot.style_stepline, offset=-5)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x98Qc.png)

I must be missing something.
Any idea about what I am doing wrong

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try adding lookahead=true in security function.

```
security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", high,lookahead=true)
```

Comment: Checking the lookahead attribute, I will use 'code' security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", high, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on, gaps=barmerge.gaps_off). Thank you again the solution